# Play! Framework 2.6! Gzip Filter if the response size is greater than 50bytes

Tags: scala, playframework, gzip, playframework-2.6

I am currently working with Play! Framework 2.6. I am looking into gzipping my response if they are greater than 80bytes. However, With the Framework there is no way to perform this. Based on this [Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/GzipEncoding)  I can make use of  the ff  code snippet

```
new GzipFilter(shouldGzip = (request, response) =>
  response.body.contentType.exists(_.startsWith("text/html")))
```

However it did not specify on where would I create this. Any idea how I can specify if it should a gzip a certain response if its greater than 50bytes?

Comment: You can create your own filter which inject a gzip filter in it, and then you test if the response should be filtered

Comment: @cgcgbcbc can you answer with an example code?

Comment: Sorry that I'm not familiar with scala, but you may look at https://www.programcreek.com/scala/play.filters.gzip.GzipFilter

Answer (score 0):

By default, the response bodies are streamed which means you do not know how big the size of the response body will be.

If you know the size of the response body already (e.g. you're serving a file from Amazon S3 already know the file size) You can set the Content-Length header and check it in `GzipFilter`.

You will also likely need to implement your own GzipFilter and adapt it so it checks the Content-Length.